# Arduino Uno R3 and ESP8266(ESP-01) serial connection

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I have done everything i found but just nothing works, or maybe i just dont understand why it wont work. Im only trying to pass data(String) from Arduino to Esp through serial comms. Please I need your help, I'm as dead as my deadlines.

Note: What I am trying to do is send data from arduino to esp and make esp send the data on a raspberry pi server through sockets. The rasp part is fine, i just need the data passed from arduino to esp.

Original Arduino code

```cpp
volatile int flow_frequency; // Measures flow sensor pulses
unsigned int l_hour; // Calculated litres/hour
unsigned char flowsensor = 2; // Sensor Input
unsigned long currentTime;
unsigned long cloopTime;
void flow () // Interrupt function
{
   flow_frequency++;
}
void setup()
{
   pinMode(flowsensor, INPUT);
   digitalWrite(flowsensor, HIGH); // Optional Internal Pull-Up
   Serial.begin(9600);
   attachInterrupt(0, flow, RISING); // Setup Interrupt
   sei(); // Enable interrupts
   currentTime = millis();
   cloopTime = currentTime;
}
void loop ()
{
   currentTime = millis();
   // Every second, calculate and print litres/hour
   if(currentTime >= (cloopTime + 1000))
   {
      cloopTime = currentTime; // Updates cloopTime
      // Pulse frequency (Hz) = 7.5Q, Q is flow rate in L/min.
      l_hour = (flow_frequency * 60 / 7.5); // (Pulse frequency x 60 min) / 7.5Q = flowrate in L/hour
      flow_frequency = 0; // Reset Counter
      Serial.print(l_hour, DEC); // Print litres/hour
      Serial.println(" L/hour");
   }
}
```

ESP

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial  ESPlease(3,1);

const char* ssid  = "sendhelp";
const char* password =  "ple4seH3lpm3";

uint16_t port = 8090;
const char* host = "192.168.1.3";

void setup()
{

  Serial.begin(9600);
  ESPlease.begin(9600);
  pinMode(3,INPUT);
  pinMode(1,OUTPUT);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.println("...");
  }

  Serial.print("WiFi connected with IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

}

void loop()
{
    WiFiClient client;

    if (!client.connect(host, port)) {

        Serial.println("Connection to host failed");

        delay(1000);
        return;
    }
    String message = "";

    Serial.println("Connected to server successful!");
    while(Serial.available()) {
      message = Serial.readString();
     // messageReady = true;
    }
    String sensorValue = message;
    String sname = "flowRate-";
    String stringThree = sname + sensorValue;

    if(sensorValue != 0){
      client.print(stringThree);
    }


    Serial.println("Disconnecting...");
    client.stop();

    delay(10000);
}
```

please help me anyone :(

Comment: SoftwareSerial on hardware Serial pins? pin mode of RX/TX changed after Serial.begin()? where do you output data in Uno? I see only a simple print to Serial

Comment: that's it, i dont know where i output code anymore. some say all i had to do was print it to serial. I know the code is full of useless stuff its because I have tried so many times already

Comment: but the useless code is in the way. clean it up